# Erro no SoapClient com php 7.1 em servidor compartilhado

Tags: php, xml, soapclient

Tenho o seguinte código que funciona perfeitamente em local host:

```
$wsdl ='http://ws.portaledu.com.br:8051/wsConsultaSQL/MEX?wsdl';

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl,array(
    'trace' => true,
    'exceptions' => true,
    'login' => $login,
    'password' => $password
));
```

Quando coloco na hospedagem, esse código retorna o erro 500:

> [24-May-2018 09:57:01 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://ws.portaledu.com.br:8051/wsConsultaSQL/MEX?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://ws.portaledu.com.br:8051/wsConsultaSQL/MEX?wsdl"
>    in /home/estiloso/public_html/fametro/resultado/teste.php:16
>   Stack trace:
>
> 0 /home/estiloso/public_html/fametro/resultado/teste.php(16): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://ws.porta...', Array)
>
> 1 {main}
>     thrown in /home/estiloso/public_html/fametro/resultado/teste.php on line 16

O que será que está faltando no servidor, estou usando o PHP 7.1

Comment: Acesso à prota 8051

Comment: @DavidAlves a porta está liberada, tanto que eu consigo abir o ´http://ws.portaledu.com.br:8051/wsConsultaSQL/MEX?wsdl´ se estivesse bloqueada nem isso abriria, não é? (E esse mesmo código apontando para esse endereço funciona no localhost)

Answer (score 1):

O seu problema está provavelmente acontecendo vindo do arquivo `php.ini`

No servidor com erro, descomente a linha:

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Retirando o `;`

Comment: no próprio retorno do `phpinfo()` verifiquei que: `OpenSSL support : 
enabled` (Está ativo)